# How to show image url in wordpress foreeach loop?

Tags: wordpress

I need to display sub categories from a particular category

```
<?php
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=22&hide_empty'); 

foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {



echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $subcategory->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $subcategory->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $subcategory->name.'</a>';


 echo '<p>'.$subcategory->description.'</p>';

}

?>
```

I tried this

```
echo '<img class='hline' src='bloginfo('template_url')/img/hline.png' alt=''>';
```

its not working

Comment: however this code work? `echo '<img class='hline' src='bloginfo('template_url')/img/hline.png' alt=''>';` you are breaking whole string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the basics of strings and concatenation in PHP.

You open your string with single quotes so you can't then use single quotes for HTML attributes unless you escape them first (`\'hline\'`). Instead you should be using double quotes for those attributes.

Then you need to break out of your string in order to use your PHP function, `bloginfo()`. With that said it makes more sense to use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead (or stylesheet directory depending on your setup).

Complete example:

```
echo '<img class="hline" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/hline.png" alt="" />';
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

I would use instead:

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

And I like to write it like this but that depends internally on you.

```
<img class="hline" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/hline.png" alt="" />';
```